# how MVC architecture applies to web application development?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I Learning about Web application and I understand MVC architecture is most used when create application but I don't understand how it applies to web application development.

Comment: If you want the shortest version with a lot of omissions then here it is: Models correspond to data you're going to use. Views correspond to pages which will present that data. Controllers correspond to the intermediate who will gather the models, call libraries that process them (if any) and then create views based on that data and send them to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Model -> Database. View  -> Represents your data. Controller -> Play
>   with Model and View. just create structure of your project like this separate your code in these three way nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

> You will find lots of answers, and lots of different opinions about this topic, but in general terms, Model is data, Controller is the processing unit (request and responses) and View is the way you represent your data in a user interface.

From the [Microsoft official book about development in MVC](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-486-developing-asp.net-mvc-4-web-applications-9780735677227) 4 I extracted this for you:

**Model**

An MVC model defines a set of classes that represent the object types that the web application manages. For example, the model for an ecommerce site might include a Product model class that defines properties such as Description, Catalog Number, Price, and others. Models often include data access logic that reads data from a database, and writes data to that database.

**Controllers**

An MVC controller is a class that handles user interaction, creates and modifies model classes, and selects appropriate views. For example, when a user requests full details about a particular product, the controller creates a new instance of the Product model class and passes it to the Details view, which displays it to the user.

**Views**

An MVC view is a component that builds the webpages that make up the web application’s user interface. Controllers often pass an instance of a model class to a view. The view displays properties of the model class. For example, if the controller passes a Product object, the view might display the name of the product, a picture, and the price